# How do I evaluate the Integral of a function g(x) using a graph?

Tags: definite-integrals, area, riemann-sum

[image]

I attempted to solve this problem in the following manner:

Part1:

The area under the curve is defined by the integral below:

$$ \int_0^{10} g(x)dx $$

and can be easily obtained by using the Area of a triangle function

$$ \frac12bh $$

which in this case would equal to

$$ \frac1210*20 = 100$$

therefore:
$$ \int_0^{10} g(x)dx = 100 $$

Part2 is another integral that is defined by the Area of a circle such that:
$$ A = \pi r^2 $$

or since it is only a Half-Circle:

$$ A = \int_{10}^{30} g(x)dx = \pi \frac {r^2}2 = 50\pi  $$

Before we can complete the 3rd part of the question you have to find:

$$ \int_{30}^{35} g(x)dx $$

using the same concept as in part1, the following is also true here:
$$ \frac12bh $$

therefore:

$$ A = \int_{30}^{35} g(x)dx = \frac12 {5} * {5}  = 12.5 $$

Now you can add it all together to say that:

$$ A = \int_{0}^{35} g(x)dx = 112.5 + 50\pi$$

however the above answer is incorrect. How can I solve this correctly based off the answer I just walked through?

Comment: The integral $\int\limits_{10}^{30} g(x)\, dx $ will be negative.

Comment: Remember that you can only write $A=\int_{10}^{30}g(x)dx$ if $g(x)$ is nonnegative for all $x\in[10,30]$. But in your graph, $-10\leq g(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in[10,30]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integrals are not all correct. Your first $2$ answers are correct, considering *only* the absolute values of the integrals. For the second and final one, observe that you have to use the concept of *positive and negative areas*, crudely speaking.

Note that the second integral is negative since the semi circle lies below the x axis.

So your second answer should actually be $\color{red}{-}50\pi$ and the final answer should be $112.5\color{red}{-}50\pi$.

Hope this helps you.